# How can I kill a service or task in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx-8

How I can stop a service or thread safely for prevent an IO exception? I have tried with the method cancel, but this isn't work. What is the guidelines ?

Comment: Go through the paragraph which starts with "In Java there is no reliable way to "kill" a thread in process..." in the [Task Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#cancel--).

Comment: You might also want to go through some of the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for this site. "this isn't work[ing]" is not a problem statement. What actually happens? Does it enter a `CANCELED` state? Does the `onSucceeded` handler still get executed? In the end, the reason it's not working the way you want (whatever that means) is (almost certainly) something to do with the way you have written the code. No-one can help you with that from the information you have provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if cancel was requested inside your Task-Loop:

```
package test;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;


public class TestTask extends Task<String>
{
    @Override
    protected String call() throws Exception
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int max = 1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            if (isCancelled())
            {
                throw new InterruptedException();
            }

            builder.append(i);
            updateProgress(i, max - 1);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```