# JavaFX: BooleanProperty equivalent of volatile boolean

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, volatile

In normal Java (non-JavaFX) environment, it is common to use `volatile boolean running` to manage a multi-threaded task. If I want to wrap this into a JavaFX property equivalent, how do I go about doing this?

I have planned to implement it this way, but I have no idea if it is correct:

```
private volatile boolean isRunning;
private final BooleanProperty running = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true) {
    @Override protected void invalidated() {
        isRunning = get();
    }
};

public final BooleanProperty runningProperty() { return this.running; }
public final boolean isRunning() { return this.running.get(); }
public final void setRunning(boolean value) { this.running.set(value); }

public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        // Do my stuff...
    }
}

// Reside in another class...
public void methodFromAnotherClass() {
    taskRunningProperty().bind(myTask.runningProperty());
}
```

The property would always be called from JavaFX Application thread, but whatever in `run()` is on another thread.

Comment: You should not change JavaFX-Property Values from another thread at all, use Platform.runLater instead:
`Platform.runLater(() -> myProperty.set(newValue));`
Also, I think what you might be looking for is `javafx.concurrent.Task`, which already implements isRunning-Property and things like that.

Comment: @rollback Added another comment - the property itself runs on main thread.

Comment: Updated my comment: Also, I think what you might be looking for is javafx.concurrent.Task, which already implements isRunning-Property and things like that.

Comment: @rollback `Task` allows you to only monitor if it is still running, but it does not allow you to stop it from the application thread... Well, unless I am mistaken somewhere...

Comment: You can call `cancel()` on a Task-Object, which must be checked via `isCancelled()` in the Task Loop to take effect. But it's possible. I answered a similar question a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919754/how-can-i-kill-a-service-or-task-in-javafx/43920571#43920571

Comment: @rollback Thanks, I think I know how I should implement this. Probably going to keep that `BooleanProperty` and call `cancel()` when the property is false.

Comment: The `BooleanProperty` would appear to be redundant once you inherit the `cancel()` functionality from `Task`. `setRunning(true)`, if it currently does anything, would be equivalent to starting the task, `setRunning(false)` would be equivalent to `cancel()`, `isRunning()` is already in the API for `Task`, as is a `runningProperty()`. You also have a `stateProperty()` to observe if you need.

Comment: @James_D The bad part about the `Task` class is that `runningProperty()` is read-only, and the only public way to stop it is via `cancel()`. All I want is just a task that stops dynamically using binding.

Comment: Well it *should* be read only in any remotely sensible API. You would not want it to be possible to set it to true if the task were in some error state that prevented it from running, for example.

Comment: @James_D Thanks, that's some awesome advice.